# This function is giving me SIGTSTP (TLE) ,Can anybody correct the code for me?

Tags: c++, vector, c++14

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

long long count(vector<long long> a){
    long long pro=0;
    sort(a.begin(), a.end(), greater<long long>());

    for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++){
        if(a[i]-i > 0){
            pro = (pro+ a[i] - i)%1000000007;
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }

    return pro;
}

int main(){
    int t,n,i;
    long long in,cnt=0;
    vector<long long> a;

    cin>>t;

    while(t--){
        a.clear();
        cin>>n;

        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            cin>>in;
            a.push_back(in);
        }

        cout<<count(a)<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

We a an array of prices of several items (a), we have to sell them to get maximum profit, but with each sell the remaining prices are dropped by 1 each.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210905/discussion-on-question-by-saheel-das-this-function-is-giving-me-sigtstp-tle-c).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your vector `a`, `pro` may overflow during the computation. To ensure that it doesn't, you can take the modulo at each loop:

```
if(a[i]-i > 0){
            pro = (pro + a[i] - i)%100000007;
        }
```